# Do I need an iPhone for TestFlight?

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

I want to share a react native app I'm building with my designer through TestFlight, but I don't have an iPhone. It seems like I need it to create a provisioning profile.

Is this true? Can I somehow use TestFlight without having to purchase an iPhone?

Comment: You need to get the uuid from an iPhone and load that into the Apple developer portal. You need at least one device registered in order to create a provisioning profile. In the medium term you will find it hard to develop for iOS without at least one iOS device. The simulator is ok but not a substitute for actual hardware.

Comment: No, You don't need it if you choose "Select a method of distribution" as the Appstore Connect.  Just in case you build Ad hoc or  Development you will need the device UUIDs to add to the provisioning  profile

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 and Nguyen Hoan! I'll try the method Nguyen suggested tonight.

Comment: It worked! Thank you Nguyen :)